# Using undefined with filter

Tags: javascript

Is it proper to check with undefined?

```
var someArray = [{pattern:/runtime/, aProperty:"tag"},
                 {pattern:/football/, aProperty:"blargh"},
                 {pattern:/restaurant/, aProperty:"olives"}]

var runtimeString = "This is a runtime string provided by a user";

/** The string provided by a user might not actually have a match in
someArray, in which case validItem would be undefined. Is there any danger 
or readability problem with comparing validItem to undefined to determine 
whether "filter" returned a result? **/

var validItem = someArray.filter(obj => obj.pattern.test(runtimeString))[0];
if (validItem !== undefined) {
    console.log("The matching item aProperty is: " + validItem.aProperty);
} else {
    console.log("There was no matching item");
}
```

Comment: Can the input match two or more patterns?

Comment: It could, but I don't care - the first valid one is all I need.

Comment: @Blackhawk indeed. Somehow confused it with find(). Will remove the previous comment to not cause confusion. My bad, need more coffee. Thanks muchly for pointing it out :)

Comment: @AnduAndrici no worries! I'm still trying to learn JS, so I look everything up just to be sure :P